# Elasticsearch partial multi_match minimum 2 letters? Want to change to 1 letter min

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using Elasticsearch to [partial] lookup in a number of words. I split the search query by space, and create a "multi_match" node per word.

This is a sample of the full list of words:

- Hill road
- High garden road
- H & M oxford road
- Hammersmith road

This is a sample generated search query, when I search for "hi road"

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "hi",
            "fields": [
              "full_text"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "road",
            "fields": [
              "full_text"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 200
}
```

I expect it to return "Hill road" and "High garden road", which it does.

Now if I search for "h road", it only returns "H & M oxford road" but I expect it to return all 4 items. Why is that? Is there a minimum of two letters per multi_match query? If so, how can I overcome it?

Thank you

Comment: Would you expect `Smith road` to be returned as well since it has `h` in the first word?

Comment: Not really because "Hammersmith" is one word and not "Hammer smith". @NishantSaini

Comment: So you want anything that starts with `H` and has `road` should match when querying for `h road`?

Comment: Also I would like to see the mapping of index as well

Comment: Actually let me correct what I said: ideally I want "Smith road" to return too, because it has h in it. Basically I want all the terms (divided by space) to be present in the list of phrases I provided.

Comment: Any suggestions @NishantSaini ?

Comment: I would suggest you to try [n-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) for this purpose. Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding my original question, any explanation why it works with 2+ characters, but not 1 characters? @NishantSaini

Comment: Its not 2+ characters is matching and not 1 character. It is because of `phrase_prefix`. Specifying this type means for `h road` it will match for something that has `h` as a term and  a term that starts with `road`. More on match prefix [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html).